# Python selenium sending wrong keys

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, keyboard

The robot opens a website which has a browser inside of it. I am trying to access a website via this browser. The browser is a video element inside the website. To open a website I need to type the url inside the video element which corresponds to the browser. The robot is able to access the website and open the browser, it clicks at the url area of the browser and cleans it. However, when I type the url inside the browser of the website, it types wrong value and I am not able to open the url which I want. The url is stored in a variable. Here´s the code:

```
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(c, 50, 25) 
    action.click()
    action.key_down(keys.Keys.CONTROL)
    action.send_keys('a')
    action.key_up(keys.Keys.CONTROL)
    action.send_keys(keys.Keys.DELETE)
    action.perform()

    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(c, 50, 25)
    action.click()
    action.send_keys(url)
    action.send_keys(keys.Keys.ENTER)
    action.perform()
```

The code works well, until this part.

I guess is not something with the keyboard because in other parts it sends the right keys.

How can I send the right url?

Is there an alternative way to send the keys I want?

Can I send the numbers or keys codes?

Thank you.

Comment: Cant you use selenium send keys?

Comment: @Pradeephebbar I am using it. However it is not sending the right keys. For example,there´s no o, and when I send q it prints c. The spacebar is also not being typed

Comment: @JaquelinePassos Is there any way you could share the url so I could test it? The docs say [`ActionChains.send_keys: "Sends keys to current focused element."`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.send_keys). Maybe the focus is somehow not on the correct element after the click?